# SQL Derby return middle of table

Tags: sql, derby

Say I have a table that looks something like this

```
COL1
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
```

With some other columns that are unimportant for this question.  If I want to return all but the first two values from 4 how would I do this with derby?

Here is the expected output to clear up what I'm wanting

```
COL1
3
3
3
3
4
5
5
6
6
```

Thanks for the help, I'm not the best with SQL but I'm trying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytab t
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(COL1) AS VAL2
            FROM mytab
            WHERE COL1 NOT IN (SELECT MIN(COL1) FROM mytab)) x
ON t.COL1 > x.VAL2
```

working example at
http://www.datagloop.com/?USERNAME=DATAGLOOP/SO_DERBY&ACTION=LOGIN

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Could you help me figure out how to drop the last two in the same query also?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses a temporary table that allows more flexibility, readability and also allows you to tune the parameters better.

The ROWID part of the queries is your position reference.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE mycol_order
    (COL1       INTEGER NOT NULL,
     TOTAL_COLS INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (COL1));

INSERT INTO mycol_order
        (COL1,TOTAL_COLS)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.COL1,
        t2.total
FROM        mytab t1,
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COL1) AS total FROM mytab) t2
ORDER BY    1;


SELECT  t.*
FROM    mytab t
    INNER JOIN mycol_order co
        ON co.col1 = t.col1
        AND co.ROWID > 2
        AND co.ROWID < co.total_cols;
```

Also updated the working example at
working example at http://www.datagloop.com/?USERNAME=DATAGLOOP/SO_DERBY&ACTION=LOGIN

Comment: PS: My version above is for SQLITE. Don't know Derby, but if it has a ROW_NUMBER() type function you could use that instead of using a temp table, but the basic logic of the query would be the same